# jQuery appends as text instead of html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following code gets a value from an Ajax json call and should append it to a div with the corresponding value. Thing is, it appends as text, not as html, so I literally see my html as text on the page. How can I fix this?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://domain.com/maprequest.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(url_array),
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(response) {
        $.each(response, function(k, v) {
            if (v != "") {
                $('.offer-list li .img a')[k].append("<div class='hoverbox'><img src='" + v + "' alt='hover' /></div>");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this on a fiddle? Something similar has happened to me before.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

By writing `$('.offer-list li .img a')[k]` you get the actual HTML element at index `k`, not a `jQuery` set. I guess your problem is caused by this.

Try this code.

```
$('.offer-list li .img a').eq(k).append("<div class='hoverbox'><img src='" + v + "' alt='hover' /></div>");
```

The `eq` function will internally filter the jQuery set for the HTML element at index `k`. See the documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/eq/).

What actually confused you is that a HTML element has the `append` and `appendChild` methods, and each respectively appends pure text, or a child node to a given element, hence your code appended the HTML as pure text.

Comment: Thanks, this solved it! Ill mark it as a solution in 5 minutes!

Comment: Thanks Zoltan, I note $($('.offer-list li .img a')[k]).append(...) also works